# DOORS DXL Relational Expression Search

Tags: ibm-doors

Does anyone have a script that will search one column for a specific text and then copy that text to a new column? The text needs to match the first 3 characters and if they match then copy the entire word which could be up to 8 characters. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's assume the attribute you're searching is 'Object Text'

First, we need to create a new attribute to hold our result - we'll call it 'New Attribute'

```
create type "String" attribute "New Attribute"
```

Next we need to add this to our view so we can see it. This code counts the number of columns and adds one at the end tied to our new attribute.

```
int z = 0
Module m = current
Column c
for c in m do {
    z++
}
c = insert ( column z )
title ( c , "New Attribute" )
attribute ( c , "New Attribute" )
width ( c , 100 )
```

Now we need to actually grab the relevant info and populate our new attribute. Let's say that we are matching the first three characters, and those are 'XYZ'. Also, let's further state that we will then go to the end of the word, so if we find an 'XYZ', go until you hit a space.

```
Object o
Regexp string_find = regexp2 "XYZ"
string item_to_search
string word_to_copy
for o in m do {
    item_to_search = o."Object Text"
    if ( string_find item_to_search ) {
        int x = start 0
        int y = end 0
        while ( ( item_to_search[ y ] != ' ' ) && ( y < length ( item_to_search ) ) ) {
            y++
        }
        o."New Attribute" = item_to_search [ x : ( y - 1 ) ]
    }    
}
```

I'm sure there's a more elegant way to set this all up, but this is the first solution that occurs to me assuming the constraints you defined are true.